# calling ajax without an external url

Tags: jquery

How to call ajax without an external file. for example if i want to delete some row i am calling an external file named delete.php to perform delete operation . i want to keep that delete.php code in main file only. suppose i have one page where several messages are there i want to keep that delete code in that page called index.php only. please guide how to do that . suppose i want to load auto scroll webpage then i dont want to call an exteral file as i have to define everything in that external file once again . so guys please tell how to call ajax url in parent file only .

Answer (score 1):

If you want to define the delete logic in the main html file you can pass a query parameter to the .ajax function then test for that parameter on the php side.

```
$.ajax(url,
{
    data: "action=delete"
    success: function(){...}
})
```

Then on the php side

```
<?php
if($_GET['action'] == 'delete'){
    logicToDelete(x);
} else if {
    logicToDisplayPage();
}
?>
```

You mentioned that you wanted to do this because you didn't want to have to re-define everything in everything again in the delete.php file. If your application has a lot of variables that every page needs, you probably want to put all of those shared things into a single file then include that file in every other file.

common.php:

```
<?php
    $setting1 = "foo";
    $setting2 = "bar";
    $setting3 = "baz";
?>
```

index.php

```
<?php
    include_once('./common.php');
    echo $setting1;
?>
```

Comment: thanks friend for your guide. i want to make auto scroll. my intention is to load data from mysql. at present i am loading 100 rows which make my page bulky . please tell how we can do this without external file.like facebook i want to refresh page header again same problem external file..please guide how to perform this operations . i have kept my all common datas in common.php file.